# Why does a pretrained spacy pipe not work when added to a spacy.blank pipe?

Tags: spacy, part-of-speech

I am trying to add spacy's already trained parser for Norwegian Bokmål to a blank spacy pipe. I get no error message when I add the pipe, but whatever the input, the pipe categorizes all tokens as nouns. What am I missing here?

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.blank("nb")
wanted_pipes = ["morphologizer", "parser"] 

for pipe_name in wanted_pipes:
  if pipe_name not in nlp.pipe_names:
    nlp.add_pipe(pipe_name, source = spacy.load("nb_core_news_sm"))
nlp.initialize()
doc = nlp("Katten heter Petrus.") # a random Norwegian sentence
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with the way you're loading the pipeline here. One is that you need a `tok2vec` for the morphologizer and parser to get meaningful input, but another is that calling `initialize` wipes their weights.

A better way to load the pipeline is to use `disable` to just exclude things you don't want, like this:

```
nlp = spacy.load("nb_core_news_sm", disable=["lemmatizer", "ner"])
```

I would recommend leaving the `attribute_ruler` in because it's fast and often works with the `morphologizer`.

Also, it should be easier to use `enable` rather than `disable` to list what you want to keep, but there's currently a bit of an issue with that. We're working on a fix, see [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/11459) for details.